# Rx.Observable.interval with different interval for each event

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, rxjs, reactive-extensions-js

I have a bunch of events, each of which has to be triggered after the previous one with a delay specific to this event.

`Rx.Observable.interval` gives a possibility to provide just one interval.

Is there a way to provide different intervals?

Comment: Have a look at #concatMap and #delay. You could return delayed observables inside concatMap (which can limit concurrency to 1, meaning the delayed observables are resolved one by one). Would that work for your usecase?

Comment: @NiklasFasching Thanks, will have a look.

Comment: @NiklasFasching  that worked as I wanted. Thanks. If you post you comment as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solutions is a modified version of what @NiklasFasching have proposed

```
   Rx.Observable.from(events)
     .concatMap(function(event) { 
        return Rx.Observable.timer(event.delay);
     })
     .subscribe(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is the `generateWithRelativeTime` operator. The official documentation is [here](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/generatewithrelativetime.md). In short, the operator lets you specify a sequence where you can tweak when you emit each value. It is similar to a for loop except that the values are emitted asynchronously at a moment of your choice.

For example, the synchronous for loop:

```
for (i=1;i<4; i++) {do something}
```

can be turned into a sequence of values separated by 100ms, 200ms, 300ms

```
// Generate a value with an absolute time with an offset of 100ms multipled by value
var source = Rx.Observable.generateWithRelativeTime(
    1, // initial value
    function (x) { return x < 4; }, // stop predicate
    function (x) { return x + 1; }, // iterator
    function (x) { return x; }, // value selector
    function (x) { return 100 * x; } // time selector
).timeInterval();
```

By tweaking the time selector to your needs, you can have the interval between values varying.

Comment: As I understood the time is not relative to previous event. What I need is to be able is to generate next value after some timeout from previous event.